Dpkg interrupted // wont configure
So i tried to “sudo apt upgrade” and it says to run “sudo dpkg —configure -s”
But that didnt work out
(check picture)
Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?


Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   You've not mentioned any OS/release, but your provided picture shows a non-Ubuntu package version

Did the command ever finish ?

Are you using kali?
